# Intern target QT webdriver on remote machine

Tags: webdriver, intern

I have installed intern on my local machine (192.168.1.50) and want to use the QT Browser webdriver on a remote machine (192.168.1.76). I've changed the intern.js and added the correct hostname as shown beneath:

```
 tunnelOptions: {
      hostname: '192.168.1.207:9517'
    },
```

The qt browser is called as well:

```
environments: [

        { browserName: 'QTBrowser', version: '5.4' , platform: [ 'LINUX' ] }
    ],
```

Tunnel is set to NullTunnel.

When executing the tests, following error is shown

> > C:\intern-tutorial>intern-runner config=tests/intern.js Listening on 0.0.0.0:9000 Tunnel started Suite QTBrowser 5.4 on LINUX FAILED Error: [POST http://192.168.1.207:9517/wd/hub/session] connect ETIMEDOUT
> >     192.168.1.207:4444   at Server.createSession     at
> >        at retry 
> >        at
> >        at
> >     runCallbacks  
> >     at    at run 
> >        at
> >        at
> >     nextTickCallbackWith0Args     at process._tickCallback
>
> TOTAL: tested 0 platforms, 0/0 tests failed; fatal error occurred
>   Error: Run failed due to one or more suite errors   at
>   emitLocalCoverage 
>      at
>   finishSuite  
>   at    at
>      at
>   runCallbacks  
>   at    at run 
>      at
>      at
>   nextTickCallbackWith0Args     at process._tickCallback

I am able to access the remote webdriver myself via the browser using url **http://192.168.1.76:9517/status**

So the connection is correct, but intern does add the /wd/hub/session which actually isn't needed.

How can I get my intern from not doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get past the 'wd/hub' issue by setting `pathname` on in the tunnel options:

```
tunnelOptions: {
    pathname: '/',
    hostname: '192.168.1.207',
    port: 9517
}
```

However, there are currently a couple of incompatibilities between Intern and QtWebDriver. One is that QtWebDriver requires that headers use a specific capitalization scheme, like 'Content-Type'. However, the library Intern uses to handle its requests currently normalizes header names to lowercase. This should be fine, because headers are supposed to be case insensitive, but not everything follows the standard.

Another problem is that, unlike most other WebDriver implementations, QtWebDriver responds to a session creation call with a 303 response rather than a 200, and the redirect address is relative. While that should be fine, the version of the Leadfoot library used by Intern doesn't properly follow relative redirect addresses.

These issues should be fixed in a future version of Intern, but for the moment Intern doesn't work out-of-the-box with QtWebDriver.